# Is there a way to convert numerical month/day/year to letter form month/day/year in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Currently, I have a column in the form month/day/year like **2/11/2020**. I am trying to get it into the form of **February Eleven 2020**.

So far I've tried looking into dt.time to split into date and month but it looks like I need it in yy-mm-dd. I was thinking I can maybe split it into three columns then use .replace on each column with a dictionary.

Does anyone know how to get this method to work or have a better solution?

Comment: Please provide a simple & reproducible code example. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a day in words?

Answer (score 0):

The following are the three I have come across.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2/11/2020']})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d %B %Y')# day/Month/Year
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%A %B %Y')#day of the week/month/Year


df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the standard datetime library has functionality to spell out the days of the month, but you can easily create your own dict to handle that.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

date_dict = {'19': 'Nineteenth',
             '20':'Twentieth',
             '21': 'Twenty First'}

print(now.strftime('%B ')  +  date_dict[now.strftime('%d')]   + now.strftime(' %Y'))

'June Twenty First 2020'
```

Here is a larger toy example if you want to use a lambda. The extra C column is added because I don't think apply works with an index.

```
import pandas as pd
dr = pd.date_range(start='6/19/2020', end='6/21/2020')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' :['6/19/2020', '6/20/2020', '6/21/2020'], 'B':[3,4,5]}, index=dr)
df['C'] = df.index
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B ')  +  date_dict[x.strftime('%d')]   + x.strftime(' %Y'))

print(df)

    A       B           C   D
2020-06-19  6/19/2020   3   2020-06-19  June Nineteenth 2020
2020-06-20  6/20/2020   4   2020-06-20  June Twentieth 2020
2020-06-21  6/21/2020   5   2020-06-21  June Twenty First 2020
```

If you just want to use an already existing string column (like column A) in m/d/y format, you can use this method.

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], dayfirst=False)
df['D'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%B ')  +  date_dict[x.strftime('%d')]   + x.strftime(' %Y'))
```

Comment: What if s(he) half a million dates

Comment: The date dictionary would only need a length of 31, no? I gave a lambda example if needed for many rows.